# How to set up Redshift SQLAlchemy in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I want to auto-increment id on Redshift.
I know that we can not use auto-increment on redshift.
But, we can use identity like auto-increment.

I created a migration like follwing.

```
op.create_table('departments',  
  sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(),redshift_identity=(1, 1), nullable=False),
  sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=256), nullable=False),  
  sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
)
```

I have SQLAlchemy model like this.

```
class Department(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'departments'  
  id = Column(Integer, redshift_identity=(1, 1), primary_key=True, unique=True)   name = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
  name = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
```

Then, I get following error when I execute the source code written below.

Error message

```
[SQL: select nextval('"departments_id_seq"')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Source code

```
from config.database import Session
from app.model.department import Department
with Session() as session:
  model = Department()
  model.name = 'test'
  session.add(model)
  session.commit()

Here is my environment
Python: 3.8
SQLAlchemy: 1.4.5
```

Do you have any guesstion for this?

Regards,